# Intent.ACTION_CALL crashing app

Tags: android

I have written this simple app to make a call based on handler delay by ms. However for some reason it crashes the app when I action the `public void callme(View view)` via button onClick event.

I am sure it is something simple, perhaps someone could point out my errors. Thanks

```
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class CallButtonActivity extends Activity {


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

          }


     public void callme(View view) {

       EditText edit_seconds = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.seconds);
       CharSequence edit_seconds_value = edit_seconds.getText();

        int mSeconds = Integer.parseInt(edit_seconds_value.toString());   

         Handler myHandler = new Handler();
         myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, mSeconds);


     }

     private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable()
     {
         public void run()
         {

             EditText msisdn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msisdn);

             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
             callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + msisdn));
             startActivity(callIntent);
         }
      };


    }
```

Comment: Please post logcat output so we can see a stack trace.

Comment: I don't run it on an emulator, just the APK on my phone, so I can't provide this.

Comment: @Rhys : **I don't run it on an emulator, just the APK on my phone, so I can't provide this.** Plug your phone to your computer and use DDMS to monitor the logcat. Either that or install a logcat app. If you can't see logcat output when trying to debug Android apps you're  giving yourself unnecessary pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line...

```
int mSeconds = Integer.parseInt(time.toString());
```

It should be `time.getText().toString()`. You also need to use `getText().toString()` for the telephone number - NOT just `getText()` as that (on an `EditText`) returns an `Editable` and not a `String`.

I'm not sure, however, if using `findViewById(...)` with a `Runnable` is legal although I may be wrong.

Comment: CharSequence edit_seconds_value = edit_seconds.getText(); int mSeconds = Integer.parseInt(edit_seconds_value.toString());  was the answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure without seeing the android manifest, but make sure you have the right permission added to AndroidManifest.xml.  Specifically, this tag should be added above the application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this required permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `msisdn` to `uri.parse`. This is an EditText! The toString method will be called but that will not pass a phone number to the parser but the identifier of the EditText object.

As you use `ACTION_CALL` there might be no further validation and the app just crashes. This should work thought:

```
EditText msisdn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msisdn);

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + msisdn.getText()));
startActivity(callIntent);
```